# navigation bar disappears when opening view controller via deep link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking

I've used a tutorial to implement a method in app delegate to open specific view controllers from a HTML button from safari. my app delegate looks like this:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open URL: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("url \(url)")
    print("url host :\(url.host!)")
    print("url path :\(url.path)")


    let urlPath : String = (url.path as String?)!
    let urlHost : String = (url.host as String?)!
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if(urlHost != "mywebsite.ir")
    {
        print("Host is not correct")
        return false
    }

    if(urlPath == "/index"){


        let innerPage: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! ViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

and my HTML button reference is:

```
<a href= "myapp://mywebsite.ir/index">open app</a>
```

but when my app home page opens, the navigation bar is gone and the user gets stuck and doesn't have any access to menu buttons or back button(in case of internal view controllers).

screenshots of home view controller before and after deep link:

[image: when navigation disappears]

[image: how it should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code as below..you should have to put your navigation controller as a window root view controller..

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
print("url \(url)")
print("url host :\(url.host!)")
print("url path :\(url.path)")


let urlPath : String = (url.path as String?)!
let urlHost : String = (url.host as String?)!
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

if(urlHost != "mywebsite.ir")
{
    print("Host is not correct")
    return false
}

if(urlPath == "/index"){


    let innerPage: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! ViewController
let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: innerPage)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
}
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
return true
```

Comment: it did the job but the navigation bar color looks faint. any idea why?

Comment: Are any appearance of navigation bar changed in your app did finish launching method? if you had any changes than same change you have to done with this navigation controller.

Comment: u're right . i've done sth like         UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
can u plz show me how to restore it?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white-->Put it in func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool method.

Answer (score 0):

Does HomeViewController is the initial ViewController? If not, you could call the initial view controller that should be the view controller with a navigation controller.

Try to do this:
`mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()`

If the behaviour persists you could embed a NavigationController on code

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! ViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Also you don't need to call window.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: my initial view controller is the navigation controller itself and i think i had a reason to choose it as the initial view controller. should i set the home controller as initial?

Comment: No, you can leave as initial.. you just need to call `mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()` instead to load your initial view controller

Comment: the line of code just resumes the application to where it was (not opening the initial vc). the later solution does the job and also shows the navigation bar. but the bar loses customizations (fonts and color). any idea?